# How can I populate a variable with a number if there's no number returned from a SELECT?

Tags: sql-server

I have this code:

```
    DECLARE @SEQ INT;

    SELECT @SEQ = MAX(SEQUENCE)
    FROM   UserTest
    WHERE  AdminTestId = 1197
    AND    UserId      = 2
```

Is there a way that I can populate @SEQ with the value of 0 if there's no record in the UserTest table with AdminTestId = 1197 and UserId = 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Isnull` or `COALESCE` function

```
DECLARE @SEQ INT;

SELECT @SEQ = MAX(SEQUENCE)
FROM   UserTest
WHERE  AdminTestId = 1197
AND    UserId      = 2

select @SEQ = Isnull(@SEQ,0) --or COALESCE(@SEQ,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @NoDisplayName is correct also you can initiate seq value

```
DECLARE @SEQ INT;
SET @SEQ = 0;

SELECT @SEQ = MAX(SEQUENCE)
FROM   UserTest
WHERE  AdminTestId = 1197
AND    UserId      = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258244.aspx) function for this.